# How to keep a menu-item selected in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my html code. How can I keep a menu-item (link to another page) selected when I'am browsing ? I'd like to do it with javascript. Thank you in advance.

```
<ul class="header-menu" id="nav">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="tour_dates.html">TOUR DATES</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by selected?

Comment: what you mean by selected? you want to highlight a `menu item` on that page so visually its clear which menu item is selected/opened?

Comment: @DeepakSharma yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: if you can not using any sort of UI framework then your page will be refreshed on clicking any menu-item and you will navigate to other page eg. home, news etc. and Im hoping each page will have this navbar html code? right? if so you can apply one css class on this navbar on each page. if navbar is reusable let us know the exact way how you done it, then only we can suggest you,

Comment: @DeepakSharma I copied this navbar in every page. I need that the nav-bar shows me the page I'am in.

Comment: simple solution without javascript will be apply a class on menu item in which page you are, like if you are on home.html apply a class class on 1st menu item, and if on news apply same class on 2nd menu item.

Comment: @DeepakSharma yes, but I want it to be dynamic. Once I have accessed the site I start with the "home.html" selected, and according to the page I change to, the highlighting must change

Comment: actually you have copy of navbar local to each page right? so if you are on home page, may be add a class to home menu-item, similar if you are on news page, add class to news menu item.  this is quick one for you as per current structure, dynamic will be more useful and needed if you have single navbar, but page content changing as per different different url, which is not your case.

Comment: notice how I have done here - https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-river-s1fse?file=/index.html

Comment: @DeepakSharma mann thank you so muchh, you save my life <3. It was so basically.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Sorry if I still disturb you an active; although I have reached my final goal, could you also tell me how it could have been done with js? always if it doesn't bother you

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that effect. Let's first state that you have an "active" class that you can use on the menu items that will make them pop out, how would you go about applying that class?

First of all, I would assign a specific class or id to all the menu items, to make them easy to reference within the css (or javascript).

Let's say that now your situation is like this:

```
<ul class="header-menu" id="nav">
    <li class="menu-item home-item"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item news-item"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item tour-item"><a href="tour_dates.html">TOUR DATES</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item gallery-item"><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item about-item"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, with javascript, you could do it like this:

```
// Get the page name
let pathArray = location.pathname.split("/");
let page = pathArray[pathArray.length-1];

// Get all menu items and convert them to an Array
let menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".header-menu .menu-item");
menuItems = new Array(...menuItems);

let lookFor = "";

// Based on the page, set the variable lookFor as the identifying class
switch (page) {
    case "home.html":
        lookFor = "home-item";
        break;
    case "news.html":
        lookFor = "news-item";
        break;
    // ...
}

// Get the element that contains the class
let item = menuItems.filter( (item) => item.classList.contains(lookFor) )[0];

// Set the "active" class on the element
item.classList.add("active");
```

Here you can check out a [codesandbox with the working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/keep-menu-item-selected-so-answer-3gzn8).

Comment: despite having copied this code there is something wrong ... I'm the wrong one

Comment: Hi daniele, no, it was also my fault for using "location.path" instead of "location.pathname". I fixed it and linked a codesandbox with the code for you to check out